# Transpose a csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and that needs to be transformed based on the two columns.

Sample snippet:

```
a,UUID_ID,c,d
1,UUID1,3,2
1,UUID2,'add',2
3,UUID3,23-2-2018,5
```

Expected output looks like this:

```
a,d,UUID1, UUID2, UUID3
1,2,2,'add',
3,5,,,23-2-2018
```

I tried reading file into pandas and creating another copy of dataframe but couldn't understand how to join them together. Any ideas how to jump start to solve this problem.

---

**FollowUp**

Sample snippet:

```
a,UUID_ID,c,d
1,UUID1,3,  # here I put nan value for d column. So 
   # in output it should still consider that
1,UUID2,'add',   # here I put nan value for d column. So
   # in output it should still consider that
3,UUID3,23-2-2018,5
```

Expected output looks like this:

```
a,d,UUID1, UUID2, UUID3
1,,2,'add',
3,5,,,23-2-2018
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`pandas.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index=['a', 'd'], columns=['UUID_ID'],
                     values='c', aggfunc='first').reset_index()

print(res)

UUID_ID  a  d UUID1  UUID2      UUID3
0        1  2     3  'add'       None
1        3  5  None   None  23-2-2018
```

Comment: I have one more question, it isn't allowing nan values in column 'a' or 'd'. instead it is completely removing that row.